# I got an error on symfony/console -- "Option does not exits". How can I allow any options even without setting it out?

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

Is it possible in symfony/console to allow all options or argument even if it didn't set on config?

You see, based from the following example. It has `->addArgument()` and `->addOption()`, it sets `name` and `yell` param and option respectively.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html

```
class GreetCommand extends Command
{

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('demo:greet')
            ->setDescription('Greet someone')
            ->addArgument(
                'name',
                InputArgument::OPTIONAL,
                'Who do you want to greet?'
            )
            ->addOption(
               'yell',
               null,
               InputOption::VALUE_NONE,
               'If set, the task will yell in uppercase letters'
            )
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $name = $input->getArgument('name');
        if ($name) {
            $text = 'Hello '.$name;
        } else {
            $text = 'Hello';
        }

        if ($input->getOption('yell')) {
            $text = strtoupper($text);
        }

        $output->writeln($text);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to run the following command without setting arguments and options?

```
$ php application.php demo:greet Fabien John Doe --yell --greet --poke
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, without refactoring base `Command` class you can't, and for good reason - all options should be validated by system and accepted. For remote CRON task, for example.

However, you can make it like this:

```
->addOption(
    'parameters',
    InputOption::IS_ARRAY,
    'Enter parameters'
);
```

This way you can treat single parameter as an array, and take validation responsibility on your own, by accessing it:

```
if ($names = $input->getOption('parameters')) {
    $text .= ' '.implode(', ', $parameters);
}
```

More info [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html).

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you this is very useful. How about options do you have any idea?

Comment: Well, I've misunderstood question first, end edited my answer. This concernes `addOption()` as well. This is ancored link to section: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#using-command-options - but unfortunately, you still have to use named arguments...

Comment: Thanks but I was able to figure out how to do it :) I did some hack.

Comment: How? I hope it did not include re-writing vendor classes : )

Comment: It's nasty... but what I did is, I get the command arguments thru $_SERVER['argv'], parse options arguments (--OPTION_NAME), then add option on runtime. Here's my code: https://github.com/paolooo/laravel-doctrine/blob/master/src/Console/DoctrineCommand.php#L105-L107

Comment: Oh... Looks fine, but raises security concerns. Be careful, and good luck!